# How do allow my website clients to send stuff to each other?

Tags: jquery, jakarta-ee, web-applications

I was thinking on something along the lines:
1. Client 1 periodically sends jQuery requests to the server using long polling technique.
2. Client 2 at some point in time sends an event to the server using regular jQuery post.
3. Server has to be aware of the fact that Client 2 has to talk to Client 1. Upon receiving the request from Client 2, server finds the pending request from Client 1 and puts the new event on the queue for Client 1 to pickup on next or current poll.

Is there a standard approaches/techniques of doing such things, Or I am on my own here and should just code it from scratch?

> EDIT: Just to clarify: by Clients I mean web browsers, by Server - Web Server. They are talking through regular HTTP requests. This client connection functionality should be an addition to my regular Dynamic Web Site project.

I am planning on using Java EE for the server side code. But it is not written in stone, in case something similar was already done on other framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) technique and the [Bayeux Protocol](http://svn.cometd.com/trunk/bayeux/bayeux.html).
There's more info at the [Dojo Foundation](http://cometd.org/)

There are a few sample implementations of browser based chat programs that have similar functionality to what you're describing. Eg the sample that comes with [AspComet](https://github.com/nmosafi/aspComet)

Comment: Thanks for useful links. That is exactly what I was thinking of.
I found this awesome project for Java web servers:  http://atmosphere.java.net/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [XMPP](http://xmpp.org/).  There are J2EE implementations available like [Apache ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/xmpp.html)

Comment: It looks like XMPP clients relays on persistent socket connection. In my case the client is a browser working through http, so stateless connection. Not sure that XMPP is a good fit here.